# How do you get the disc space occupied by symlink pointed files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a list of file that are symlinked for original file

I was trying to get the size of those files as

```
filePath="/ready/PPMI_3651^SI82-SI108^PPMI_WES/PPMI_3651.r1.fq.gz"
size="$(du -ch $filePath | tail -1 | cut -f 1)"
```

but it only gives me `0` size. How  do I get the space occupied by those?

This is how the file looks:

```
[un@xc transfer_data]$ ls -lht /ready/PPMI_3651^SI82-SI108^PPMI_WES/PPMI_3651.r1.fq.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 uuds parkd 70 May 16  2017 /ready/PPMI_3651.r1.fq.gz -> ../splitRG/PPMI_3651.r1.fq.gz
```

Comment: See the `-H` and `-L` arguments to `du`. This is arguably more of a tool-usage question than a software-development question, making it a better fit for [unix.se] rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man du`:

```
   -L, --dereference
          dereference all symbolic links
```